# Tag synonyms / merge? User-testing and usability-testing

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [user-testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-testing) and [usability-testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability-testing) co-exist as separate tags, or should they be combined?

I personally don't like the [user-testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-testing) as it implies it's the user that is being tested, so [usability-testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability-testing) is a far better one to use.

Shall we do something with these two tags, or are they both fine kept separate?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the user-testing tag is dead wrong. We can’t and shouldn’t test users. This is up to those with the competence in health care like doctors and nurses. Users are what they are, and we don’t test users.

However, we want users to test applications, devices and solutions. We study users’ response to the stimuli we give them. We monitor facial expressions, time sequence of actions and question them afterwards.

That is to me (with English as second language) usability testing at the highest abstraction level.

I’m all for a merge.

Comment: Merge: Complete!